# Do Javax and Hibernate Validations imply NotNull?

Tags: java, annotations, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

The list of supported Javax Validations are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html).

The list of supported Hibernate Validations (extending Javax) are [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/package-summary.html).

**Do each of these annotations "extend" or imply `@NotNull`?**

For instance, if I annotate the following entity:

```
public class Widget {
    @Email
    private String email;

    @URL
    private String website;

    // etc...
}
```

Does `@Email` and `@URL` also enforce `@NotNull`? Or are they simply applied/enforced *if* those properties are defined for a particular `Widget` instance?

Which annotations extend/imply `@NotNull`, and which ones don't? Are there any other implied relationships with these annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/dfa65141d63cbfbb33f79522f6ba40a6d2b29b5c/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/EmailValidator.java#L58) of [`EmailValidator`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/EmailValidator.html) from hibernate validator for example, it contains this code at the beginning of `isValid()` method:

```
if ( value == null || value.length() == 0 ) {
    return true;
}
```

Same for `URLValidator` and so on. Generally all validators for the corresponding annotations consider the value valid when you try to validate `null` value, so a good rule of thumb would be to always perform the not-null validations separately.

**Edit:** here is a quote from [JSR-303 specification](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) related to this issue:

> While not mandatory, it is considered a good practice to split the
>   core constraint validation from the not null constraint validation
>   (for example, an @Email constraint will return true on a null object,
>   i.e. will not take care of the @NotNull validation)